# How to set more than 2 images on ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on assignment, and have a problem. I need to have 2 clicks on ImageView control,meaning I have 3 photos total. When I set imageview control to show one photo, and on click, it switches to second photo, it all works good. Problem is that I can't switch to 3rd photo. Anyone can help? How can I add one more "click" to switch from 2nd to 3rd photo?

Comment: use a variable called counter , increment it when you click, use modulo division, use an if condition check it perform the task related to that ! If you didn't get it ask!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter, in each click update the imageView based on the counter value ( if 0 it's first image, else if it's 2 second image and the same for the third image), and increment the counter by 1 on each click and make sure value of counter doesn't exceed 3.

```
     int counter = 0;

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateImageView(counter);
            counter++;
            counter %= 3;
        }
    });

   void updateImageView(int counter) {
        if(counter == 0)
            set first Image
        else if(counter == 1)
            set second Image
        else
            set third Image
    }
```